# Device theme mode does block app theme mode. Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-styles, darkmode

I started to implement Night/Light mode inside my android app by using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYJ1WwwnvCo&list=PLhbb5rsrqfXhuDi19o8ZmMlvl7HWXsPua&index=1&ab_channel=ARSLTech).

But devices has this function by system. The problem is that the system night mode does block my code in app. How does this happen??

- If device mode is dark, but in the app, the background is white, it doesn't work. (background is dark)
- If device mode is in light mode, but in the app, the status bar background is black, it doesn't work. (status bar is white)

How to resolve that? Thanks.

---

**DayNight:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorGrey</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppModalStyle"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_curved</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:buttonTint">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorBlack">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorWhite">#000</color>
    <color name="colorGrey">#808080</color>

    <color name="colorBackground">#1A1A1A</color>
    <color name="colorBottomMenu">#000</color>
</resources>
```

---

**Light:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorGrey</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppModalStyle"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_curved</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:buttonTint">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#000</color>
    <color name="colorBlack">#000</color>
    <color name="colorWhite">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorGrey">#808080</color>

    <color name="colorBackground">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorBottomMenu">#fff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are you testing on android 10 or higher?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the light or dark mode locally and check it while the app is opening, and you can fix the mode accordingly.

```
    public class MainApp extends Application {
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
    
//https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences
            boolean isNightMode = new MySharedPref(this).isDarkMode(); //sharedpreferences...
    
            if (isNightMode) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already have it

Comment: So you already did that, right?

Comment: Yes, I change theme by checkbox

Comment: Are you following with the checkbox listener?
If you are following and setting it as default mode when the situation changes, it should be fine. The code I shared above will actually be used when opening the app, so if you only do this after the checkbox process, it cannot be saved when the app is restarted.

Comment: I know what happens. If I try to use activity_main background red (device theme is black) it works fine, but if I change red to white. Background must be white, but it is black

Comment: do you just want to change the activity_main background color ? Frankly, I didn't fully understand. If you want, you can share the screenshots, maybe it will work by editing the question.

Comment: I want to make a theme switch in real time regardless of the dark mode of the phone. And also switch background color dark/light. It's like the phone looks for light colors and changes to dark gray.

Answer (score 1):

`Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` is all you need ...

in combination with `values/styles.xml` and `values-night/styles.xml`.